# Cannot find control with name in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, form-control

Cannot find control with name notes. Why is that the control name is not recognized?

As you can see on the template I have control name notes.

#Code

```
initFormGroups(): void {
    const sectionGroups = {};
    this._sections.forEach((section: TemplateSection, sectionIndex: number) => {
      const sectionGroup = {};

      section.questions.forEach(({ rephrase, question, notes }: Question, questionIndex) => {
        sectionGroup[questionIndex] = [rephrase || question];         
      });

      sectionGroups[sectionIndex] = this.formBuilder.group(sectionGroup);

      return null;
    });

    this.form = this.formBuilder.group(sectionGroups );
  
  }
```

#my template

```
 <form [formGroup]="form" name="form" *ngIf="form">
          <ng-container *ngFor="let section of _sections; let sectionIndex = index">
                    <mat-card class="question" *ngFor="let question of section.questions; let questionIndex = index">
                      <ng-container *ngIf="question.notes">

                        <mat-form-field appearance="outline"
                           class="pr-4 clickable-mat-form-field"
                           (click)="editNote(sectionIndex, questionIndex, question)"
                           >
                          <mat-label>Note</mat-label>
                          <input class="hidden" matInput>
                            <editor class="mat-input-element"
                              [disabled]="true"
                              matInput formControlName ="notes"
                              [init]="tinyMCEConfig">
                            </editor>
                        </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here? dynamically initialize `this.form` based on the template? What is `this._sections`?

Comment: On a first hunch, I'd say it can't find notes because you never added any formControl with the name `notes` to your `formGroup`. Could you maybe add a `debugger` point or `console.log()` after creating the from, so after the line `this.form = this.formBuilder.group(sectionGroups );` and then add the value of the form to your question. It'll make it easier to understand.

I think the formControls will have numbers (indexes) for names.

Comment: @BotondBéres _sections is an array of objects

Comment: @RubenSzekér , how would I add a formcontrol name for notes on my formgroup Sir ?

Comment: @RubenSzekér can you post an example answer Sir based on what you described.

Comment: section.questions contains the notes , section.questions is an array of objects , how am I going to pull the notes from the loop and add it to the formGroup?

Comment: @MarkLatin check [this imgur image](https://imgur.com/a/utwpKP7). I think you are using the wrong formControlName in your case, but I'm not sure, this is just a hunch. It'd be very useful if you'd be able to post (part of) your code on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com), this way we can see what's exactly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have `*ngIf="form"` so your entire template does not exist until you set `this.form`

Comment: m, can you elaborate more about this Sir?

Comment: I don't think this is the issue. In fact, I think it is good to do this, because if you do not do this you will get various errors that the formGroup does not exist upon loading the view since the FormGroup is created after the view is loaded.